# Filter with partition over in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, partition

Here is that I would like to have

```
select 
    *,  
    rank() over (partition by col_a order by col_b) as some_rank 
from 
    table_A
where 
    some_rank = 1
```

Obviously, this is not going to work. I can use CTE or temp table to get what I want, but I wonder if can do it all at once (without CTE or temp table). Something like `having` with `group by`

Comment: Just a note that using this method to filter rows can be bad for performance. The problem is that you are scanning the entire table then sorting it by your definition before elminating any rows from the result set. If you can accomplish the same thing through traditional aggregation methods like `max` I would highly recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `top (1)` with `ties`  clause :

```
select top (1) with ties ta.*
from table_A ta
order by rank() over (partition by col_a order by col_b);
```

Only the sadness is, you can't filter out rows which are greater than 1 & this has some performance downgrades.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this old fashioned way

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
    select 
        *,  
        rank() over (partition by col_a order by col_b) as some_rank 
    from 
        table_A
    ) T
WHERE some_rank = 1
```